# Change icon image JavaFX

Tags: image, icons, javafx

How can I change the icon image of my JavaFX application?

And is possible to run my application without java installed on computer?

Comment: What is your [JavaFX application execution mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm#CEGHEAHD)? (and one question per question please).

Comment: I think is "Run as a standalone program"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("yourImage.extension"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the image of your primary stage

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage)
{    
   stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon.png"));
}
```

And yes you can run your application on a system without the run-time, for this you must have the run-time embedded in your application

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your second question, I know this exists, but I never used it. 
That would be a self contained app. Check this site:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm