# JavaFx - Where to change the app icon

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I implemented the desktop application using JavaFx. Now I want to change the default app icon.
What I did is, I created one folder under the project called "package" under this I created one more folder called "windows" like "project/pakage/windows/appname.ico". and then I created the excutable. But here the problem was the executable icon was changed but deatils icon was not changed. Please help where we can change that icon. please refer the below screen shot.

[image]

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer, it shows how to set Icon to a Javafx Application, you can replace the icon location or put it in class path :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21720384/1759128